# How to animate image in a canvas using tweenlite

Tags: javascript, canvas, gsap

Been searching for a while now and I haven't seen any article on how to animate (loop continuously from right to left) an imaged drawn in a canvas

```
var context = document.getElementById('my-canvas').getContext('2d');
var cloud   = new Image();
cloud.src   = 'images/cloud.png';
cloud.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(cloud, 0, 0)
    TweenLite.to({x:0,y:0}, 2, {x: 200, y: 200});
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

**edit:**

Like so but using tweenlite : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDQ6b/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Your first argument is wrong, it needs to be the target element/object **[according to their documentation](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/to/)**:

```
TweenLite.to(target, duration, vars);
```

where `target` is an object/element, `duration` as a number, and `vars` an object.

Example:

```
TweenLite.to(canvas, 2, {x: 200, y:200});
```

Just note that if you intend to use the canvas element as target you could might as well just animate the image directly when loaded.

If you intend to move it across the canvas' bitmap without moving the canvas itself you will need to use a custom object (as I understand their docs) as target holding f.ex. the `x` and `y` properties, and use the `onUpdate` callback mechanism. Check their documentation for all the gory details.

```
var myObj = {
        x: 0,     // start position
        y: 0,
        image: cloud
    };

TweenLite.to(myObj, 2, {x: 200, y:200, onUpdate: drawImage});

function drawImage() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(myObj.image, myObj.x, myObj,y);
}
```

Just replace what you have inside the `onload` handler with the code above.

Disclaimer: highly untested..